# Postfix send e-mail on behalf of G Suite

Tags: linux, debian, postfix, sendmail, smtp

I have a domain registered on G Suite and I'm building a app that needs to send Transactional email such as password recovery and email verifies. The smtp for gmail has a low quota for that. I need to build a server running postfix to send e-mails SPF registered for gmail so I can bypass that limit. Yes I have seen services like mailgun but i need to build one because of cost. I'm totally new to email serving so could any one give me at least some tips on how could I achieve that? keeping my domain on google but sending email form a specific account from my postfix debian server. Also, I'm using Google cloud.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to send emails that claim to be from a Gmail domain unless they really come from Gmail's servers. (Well, I suppose you can send them but they'll be tagged as probable forgeries by the recipient servers.)

The reason for this is that Gmail, along with most other email providers, identifies valid SMTP sender addresses in its SPF record, and signs all outbound email with its DKIM certificate.

```
dig txt gmail.com          # Starts the process
dig txt _spf.google.com    # Some more...
```

Some potentially useful off-site references. These in turn may provide links to further information.

- [G Suite Admin - Email sending limits](https://support.google.com/a/answer/166852?hl=en)
- [Everything you need to know about SPF](https://www.dmarcanalyzer.com/spf/)
- [How to Explain DKIM in Plain English](https://blog.returnpath.com/how-to-explain-dkim-in-plain-english-2/)
- [What is DMARC?](https://dmarc.org/)